# How to create a private key in TPM, create a CSR and lock down the TPM?

Tags: .net, wpf, certificate, windows-10, tpm

Our app (C#, Win10, WPF) needs to store a private key for signing of messages sent to a hardware device. This device trusts our CA so I want the CA to sign a certificate for us.

I have been looking into TPM APIs on Windows but I am having trouble figuring out how to create a private key, store it in the TPM, create a CSR and then lock down the TPM so no process can read the private key or modify it. I ideally I would like to restrict TPM access so only certain processes can sign data with that key.

Does anyone know how to go about this in Windows 10 and what APIs to use?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:
https://security.stackexchange.com/a/179422/68088

You'll need to create an inf file with configuration parameters.  The TPM converts that into a CSR, which you can send over to your CA.  The above guide is especially useful on a Windows 10 machine if it is equipped with a TPM.

Comment: so from the link above we can setup a certreq config file specifying the TPM as the key provider.  Question: once we get the certificate back from a CA and install it into the Windows Certificate Store, how is this certificate associated with the private key that is in the TPM?

Comment: @lee23: The TPM allows the public key from a key pair to be signed by a certificate authority, whereas the corresponding private key is protected by the TPM. That's what a certificate is. It's a public key that also contains information about a trusted third party, such as a chain of trust from primary to intermediate certificate authorities. But the essential ingredient within that certificate (and certificate signing request) is the public key. A signed cert lets other clients have confidence in the public key (whose private key counterpart remains protected by the TPM).

Comment: But when I want to use it for say WCF authenticate, the private key is required to be imported together with the certificate (a pfx) into the certificate store no?